# All the requests that I make are visible in the network tab of the developer tools when I inspect the web page using F12 (i'm using flutter web)

Tags: flutter, security, devtools, dio

i'm working on flutter web project , i'm using dio package to make the requests like this
[image: This is the base function for making POST requests where I simply give it the endpoint and the data as a parameters.]

And this how i call the function :

[image: This is the calling of the function to make the request .]

The problem is :

if i press f12 to open the dev tools (or right click and open inspect ) then open network tab i will see all the request informations (headers ,data ,response , url) every thing about it like this .

[image: If i double click on the request i will see all the information about it even the response .]

I'm trying to hide or encrypt all of this requests but i don't know how can i do this .